# Special operations on a list

Tags: list-manipulation

How to write this code in a better way to be faster?

```
mat1 = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {j, h}}}

L1 = {{a, c}, {e, j}}

L2 = {{b, d}, {f, h}}

IL1 = Inverse[L1]

IL2 = Inverse[L2]

mat2 = {{{IL1[[1, 1]], IL2[[1, 1]]}, {IL1[[1, 2]], 
    IL2[[1, 2]]}}, {{IL1[[2, 1]], IL2[[2, 1]]}, {IL1[[2, 2]], 
    IL2[[2, 2]]}}}
```

In my original code each one of nested lists contains 10 elements:

```
mat1={{{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10},{b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10}},
      {{c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10},{d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10}}}
```

I want to form ten 2x2 matrices and find the inverse of each one, then I want to form  a block matrix `mat2` of the same from of `mat1`.

Comment: when i used `Part` or `Extract` functions, the running became so slow. I need  to write fast code

Answer (score 6):

One-liner:

```
Transpose[Inverse /@ Transpose[{{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {j, h}}}, {2, 3, 1}], {3, 1, 2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

```
mat2 = Flatten[Inverse /@ Flatten[mat1, {{3}, {1}}], {{2}, {3}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Original post:**

Perhaps:

```
mat1 = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {j, h}}};
IL1 = Inverse[mat1[[All, All, 1]]];
IL2 = Inverse[mat1[[All, All, -1]]];
mat2 = Transpose /@ Transpose[{IL1, IL2}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It works, thank you